# Can't access property of object in ternary equation but works otherwise in JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a object that is like the following:

```
campground
{
  "uri": "/campgrounds/long-island-bridge-campground-llc/",
  "acfDetails": {
    "picture": {
      "mediaItemUrl": "/uploads/2021/04/longislandbridge.png"
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to use a ternary condition to check if campground.acfDetails.picture.mediaItemUrl exists. Right now I have this code:

```
campground.acfDetails.picture.mediaItemUrl != null ? (<img src="campground.acfDetails.picture.mediaItemUrl"></img>) : <> </>
```

Which gives me a error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'picture' of undefined
```

But, if I change it to:

```
campground.acfDetails != null ? (<img src="campground.acfDetails.picture.mediaItemUrl" alt="HI"></img>) : <> </>
```

It will show the image if it exists, but otherwise will just show "HI".

I don't understand why the object exists in one location but breaks in the other. Would appreciate any guidance.

Thank you!

Comment: Are there any asynchronous operations during the construction of `campground`?

Comment: Yes, sorry, it uses Apollo to put together a list of campgrounds, and then i'm mapping through them.

Comment: Setting `src="campground.acfDetails.picture.mediaItemUrl"` assigns the string literal to `src`, not the actual URL to the png file you intended.  Am I mistaken?

Comment: Sorry, it's being looped over in a map statement, so it does assign it the URL.

Comment: I'm not seeing how the `map` statement would substitute the URL for the string literal.  Can you show more code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in the first example:

```js
campground.acfDetails.picture.mediaItemUrl ? (<img src="campground.acfDetails.picture.mediaItemUrl"></img>) : <> </>
                     ^ here
```

In this case if `campground.acfDetails` is `undefined` or `null` you're trying to access a property of `undefined` or `null` which will throw an error.

So to really test the existance of the property `mediaItemUrl` you'd have to insert `?` if the object before could be `null` or `undefined`:

```js
campground.acfDetails?.picture.mediaItemUrl ? (<img src="campground.acfDetails.picture.mediaItemUrl"></img>) : <> </>
                     ^ here
```